# Kafka producer with spring kafka template factory implementation

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple rest api (Approach 1) , which produces message sends to kafka cluster using kafka-clients api .

Spring boot rest -> producer.send (kafka-clients lib) -> kafka cluster

Additionally i also have another implementation (Approach 2)

Spring boot rest -> producer factory implementation (single configuration spring object) -> kafka template send (spring-kafka) -> kafka cluster

I observed that approach 2 takes more time than approach 1. Say for example approach1 for a single message took 40 ms, approach 2 took nearly 100ms.

I wanted to  minimize the time taken to push messages using producer factory based implementation. Any thoughts on how to tweak it ?

Implementation details below : (Producer factory)

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${bootstrap.servers}")
    String bootStrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,Object> configs(){
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootStrapServers);
        properties.put("acks", "0");
        properties.put("retries", 0);
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String,String> factory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String,String> template(){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory());
    }
}
```

```
Controller : 

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String,String> template;

    public ResponseEntity<String> producer(@PathVariable String topicName, @RequestBody String requestBody) throws JsonProcessingException {

        try {
             template.send(topicName,requestBody);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        } finally {
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Comment: can you show the custom producer factory  configuration properties ?

Comment: @Deadpool  properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootStrapServers);
  properties.put("acks", "0");
        properties.put("retries", 0);
  properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Comment: @Deadpool -  I used default values of producer config. Didnt add anything in properties for configuration.

Comment: Show your code and configuration (edit the question, not in a comment). The `KafkaTemplate` is a very lightweight wrapper around a `KafkaProducer` so shouldn't add much overhead.

Comment: @GaryRussell code added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see more overhead than I would have expected (similar to your results). I will do some profiling to see if it can be improved.

Frameworks will always add some overhead, but the bottom line is, as with all Spring projects, you can still drop down to the lower level APIs, should the need arise.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65791199Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65791199Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template,
            ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {

        return args -> {
            StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = template.send("so65791199", "foo");
            future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
            watch.start("template");
            IntStream.range(0, 10000).forEach(i -> {
                futures.add(template.send("so65791199", "foo"));
            });
            for (ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> fut : futures) {
                fut.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            watch.stop();

            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(pf.getConfigurationProperties());
            ProducerRecord<String, String> pr = new ProducerRecord<>("so65791199", 0, null, "foo");
            Future<RecordMetadata> fut = producer.send(pr);
            fut.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            watch.start("raw producer");
            List<Future<RecordMetadata>> futs = new LinkedList<>();
            IntStream.range(0, 10000).forEach(i -> {
                futs.add(producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("so65791199", 0, null, "foo")));

            });
            for (Future<RecordMetadata> futr : futs) {
                futr.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            watch.stop();
            producer.close();
            System.out.println(watch.prettyPrint());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so65791199").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
StopWatch '': running time = 126595537 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
088742103  070%  template
037853434  030%  raw producer
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis